# Subscribe with live bookmark

Tags: php

Hi when i am using xml file for wap application then its displaying that Subscribe with live bookmarks with dialog box with two options Subscribe and cancel. Can you please tell me how to remove this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the wrong `Content-Type` HTTP header.